# Is there a best method to evaluate URL variables to determine the appropriate page?

Tags: url, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 9.0.1.

I have a new web site that uses Bikes.cfm and Makers.cfm as template pages. I need to be able to pass BikeID and MakerID to both of the these pages, along with other variables.  I don't want to use the Actual page name in the URL, such as this:

```
MyDomain.com/Bikes.cfm?BikeID=1234&MakerID=1234
```

I want my URL to look more like this:

```
MyDomain.com/?BikeID=1234&MakerID=1234
```

I need to NOT specify the page name in the URL.

I want these two URLs to access different data:

```
MyDomain.com/?BikeID=1234&MakerID=1234 // goes to bike page
MyDomain.com/?MakerID=1234&BikeID=1234 // goes to maker page
```

So, if BikeID appears in the URL before MakerID, go to the Bikes.cfm page. If MakerID appears before BikeID, go the Makers.cfm page.

Is there an easy and existing method to arrange the URL keys in such a way to have them point to the appropriate page?

Should I just parse the the URL as a list and determine the first ID and go to the appropriate page? Is there a better way?

Any thoughts or hints or ideas would be appreciated.

**UPDATE** -- It certainly appears that using the order of parameters in a URL is a bad idea for the following reasons:

1) many programs append variables to the URL
2) some programs may reorder the variables
3) GoogleBot may not consider order relevant and will most likely not index the site correctly.

Thanks to everyone who provided advice in a positive manner that my approach was probably a bad idea and would not produce the results I wanted.  Thanks to everyone who suggested alternate means to produce the results I wanted.

If anyone of you positive people would like to put your positive comment/advice as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as the answer.

Comment: Why in the world would you do such a thing?  I've never heard of a scheme that actually treats URL variable order as a relevant consideration; sounds crazy.

Comment: If BikeID is first, it means that the primary requested is on the bike, which is why we go to Bikes.cfm. If there is a BikeID followed by a MakerID, the bike is the primary focus and the maker is a secondary focus.  If MakerID is first, the focus of the request on the bike maker, which is why they are taken to Makers.cfm. If there is a BikeID, we put that bike at the top of their bike listings because we will know that they are interested in a specific bike.

Comment: This is certainly going to come back to bite you. You can't be sure what the order of parameters in the URL string is going to be. You should at the very least add a parameter that explicitly says which page to load. It needn't be complex; something like `q=b` (to indicate the "Bike" page) should be sufficient. Then you needn't worry at all about the URL parameter order.

Comment: Al, thanks for that bit of advice. I am fully aware of stuff being appended to URLs, but I have never heard of URLs being mangled at will by rogue programs. Do you have any evidence that this actually happens?

Comment: I wouldn't say mangled. Nor would I call them "rogue". I would say that virtually anything that deals with URLs will see URL parameters `bikeid=1234&makeid=1234` and `makeid=1234&bikeid=1234` as identical. (For instance googlebot.) If you need to manipulate the URL query string using the URL scope, guess what? The keys in that structure could be in any old order. You simply can't count on URL parameters being in a specific order. That way lies heartache.

Comment: As Al mentioned - googlebot will consider both url the same and it may do some harm to your website's SEO. It's weird idea anyway. Maybe try using cgi.http_referrer to decide how to display the page if you don't want to put anything additional in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite my grave misgivings about the whole idea, here's how I would do it if I were forced to do so:

index.cfm:

```
<cfswitch expression="#ListFirst(cgi.query_string, '=')#">

  <cfcase value="BikeID">
     <cfinclude template="Bikes.cfm">
  </cfcase>

  <cfcase value="MakerID">
     <cfinclude template="Makers.cfm">
  </cfcase>

  <cfdefaultcase>
     <cfinclude template="Welcome.cfm">
  </cfdefaultcase>

</cfswitch>
```

Comment: "Grave misgivings"? Really? And yet you didn't bother to mention why it might be a bad idea.

Comment: As others will probably comment, the order of URL parameters are *nearly* never taken into account. This is due to the way various web-servers handle the automatic appending of query params to the URL string. As a rule of thumb, you should typically never build into your application logic the expectation that they will always be in a certain order--but rather--if they exist at all, and what their values are.

Comment: Thanks Shawn - you expressed my thoughts well.

Comment: I'd personally would use "friendly URLs" and not go off the placement order of the URL variables.  You'd instead be doing something like: http://mydomain.com/Bikes/1234/1234/ and http://mydomain.com/Makers/1234/1234/ instead of http://MyDomain.com/Bikes.cfm?BikeID=1234&MakerID=1234 and http://MyDomain.com/Makers.cfm?BikeID=1234&MakerID=1234

This could be done via any number of URL Rewrite modules.  MS has one that is free for IIS for example.